# last-of-type issue with some img tag

Tags: html, css, padding

I have some `<img>` tag which will be load some images via the php code.

The following code :

```
<div class="images_cd">
    <img src="<?php the_field('case_image9'); ?>" alt="" />
<img src="<?php the_field('case_image9'); ?>" alt="" />
<img src="<?php the_field('case_image10'); ?>" alt="" />
</div>
```

I would like to add 50 px padding-bottom for each img tag, but for the last one i don't one that padding.

Here is my CSS :

```
.images_cd{

}
.images_cd img{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.images_cd img:last-of-type{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

But the last img still get the 50px padding as well as 0 padding.
And the thing is the -50 px is also not working for that.

What is the problem?

Comment: If you're testing in ie8 then it won't work because ie8 doesn't support last-of-type or last-child

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code as written, but added some outlines so you could see things and it's working just fine.

```
.images_cd{
    width:400px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.images_cd img{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.images_cd img:last-of-type{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EW33R/1/) and verify that there's no margin-bottom on the last img.

My guess is that something else must be overriding that CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.images_cd img:last-child { }
```

instead

Comment: +1, but you should not use the phrase "try" - good answers have been downvoted for this :)